# clock_gettime() versus time command

Tags: profiling, clock

I am trying to understand a large discrepancy between the running times of a program as measured by clock_gettime() and by the UNIX time command.  The program uses clock_gettime() to measure its total running time.  It reports that the time taken by the program is about 0.5 seconds.  The time command on the other hand reports that both the real time and the user time are about an order magnitude less, 0.06 seconds. (System time is ~0.006s.)  This happens on across different clock ids with clock_gettime() different clock ids. (So far I have tried CLOCK_MONOTONIC, CLOCK_REALTIME, and CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW.) I have also tried different time subtraction [functions.](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html) The discrepancy happens on two different Linux machines and is consistently reproducible.  The times reported by clock_gettime() and the time command match for longer running inputs fairly closely.

Any ideas for what could be causing this?